# Add data in database on button click

Tags: html, database, adodb

I want to add data in the database when i click on button. I am a newbie to html. This is the thing I am trying to do. Please help.

```
var name=name.value;
var pass=pass.value;
var cn = newActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = C:/login.mdb"; 
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset"); 

var SQL = "insert into login(name="" +name+,pass="" +pass);"

cn.Open(strConn);
rs.Open(SQL,cn);

name.value=rs(1);
pass.value=rs(2);

rs.Close();
cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You write wrong query of insert.

> var SQL = "insert into login(name="" +name+,pass="" +pass);"

Try this Query.

> var SQL = "insert into login values(name="" +name+,pass="" +pass);"
>
> Connection = New OledbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;" &
>   _ "Data Source=C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\code\Customers.mdb" )

check this

> [LINK](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/721580-save-input-html-access-database-using-javascript)

Comment: still the data is not getting inserted

Comment: @Sherry which databas connection you using?

Comment: check your database connection path

Comment: i mean to say the database connection path is correct, but the data is still not getting inserted.